# Angular 2 event subscription not working

Tags: angular

I am firing an Angular 2 event but the subscribed function is not getting run.

In one file I have this code which subscribe to the event:

```
listenToLoginEvents() {

this.events.subscribe('user:login', () => {
  this.loading.dismiss();
  this.nav.setRoot(VeeUPage);
});

this.events.subscribe('user:loginFailed', (error) => {
  this.loading.dismiss();
  this.showAlert("Login Error", error);
});

this.events.subscribe('user:resetPassword', (result) => {
  this.showAlert("Forgotten Password", result);
});

this.events.subscribe('user:resetPasswordFailed', (error) => {
  this.showAlert("Forgotten Password", error);
});
}

showAlert(title, subtitle) {
let alert = Alert.create({
  title: title,
  subTitle: subtitle,
  buttons: ['Ok']
});
this.nav.present(alert);
}
}
```

The code which fires the event looks like this:

```
resetPassword(email) {
var ref = new Firebase(this.firebaseUrl);
ref.resetPassword({
  email: email
}, (error) => {
  var errMessage = '';
  if (error) {

    switch (error.code) {
      case "INVALID_USER":
        errMessage = "Could not find an account with that email address.";
        break;
      default:
        errMessage =  "There was an error resetting your password.";
    }
    this.events.publish('user:resetPasswordFailed', errMessage);
    alert('Sent resetpasswordfailed event');
  } else {
    this.events.publish('user:resetPassword', "You have just been sent a password reset email.");
  }
});
```

}

Comment: Looks like your subscription is not set before event publish.  From where you are invoking listenToLoginEvents function

Comment: Added this as answer as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if your subscription is not set before your event publish.

If you move the invokation of. `listenToLoginEvents()` function such that it is called before publishing it will work .
Possible places for calling this may `constructor` or `ngOnInit`